# unwanted caching of db results or model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I have a controller action which i am performing some work on (example below)

```
        public ActionResult Dashboard()
        {
        // Redirect back to login page if not authenticated
        if (!this.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return this.RedirectToAction(string.Empty, "Account");
        }

        this.ApplicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        this.UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(this.ApplicationDbContext));
        var user = this.UserManager.FindById(this.User.Identity.GetUserId());

        MyRitualDashboardData model = new MyRitualDashboardData();
        Member member = db.Members.Single(m => m.AspNetUserId == user.Id);
        model.Gravatar = string.Format("<img src='{0}' class='gravatar img-circle'/>", user.PhotoUrl);
        model.UserMember = member;
        model.UserHomeLocation = member.getUserHomeLocation();
        model.UserActiveMembership = member.getActiveMembership();
        model.UserPastMemberships = member.getExpiredMemberships();
        model.UserPayments = member.getUserPayments();
        model.UserStatistics = member.GetMembershipStatistics();
        if (model.UserActiveMembership != null)
        {
            model.DaysTillMembershipExpiry = member.getActiveMembership().daysTillExpiry();
        }

        return this.View(model);
    }
```

If i run this code and perform some changes to the database with some other actions then when i refresh my dashboard the various updates that i am making to the member profile is fine.

If however i try to re-factor my code and place the above code into a seperate class and use a static method to do the call like so:

```
        public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        // Redirect back to login page if not authenticated
        if (!this.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return this.RedirectToAction(string.Empty, "Account");
        }

        this.ApplicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        this.UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(this.ApplicationDbContext));
        var user = this.UserManager.FindById(this.User.Identity.GetUserId());

        MyRitualDashboardData model = new MyRitualDashboardData();
        model = MyRitualService.GetModelForMyRitual(user);

        return this.View(model);
    }
```

and have a method in a seperate class like so:

```
        public static MyRitualDashboardData GetModelForMyRitual(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        MyRitualDashboardData model = new MyRitualDashboardData();
        Member member = db.Members.Single(m => m.AspNetUserId == user.Id);
        model.Gravatar = string.Format("<img src='{0}' class='gravatar img-circle'/>", user.PhotoUrl);
        model.UserMember = member;
        model.UserHomeLocation = member.getUserHomeLocation();
        model.UserActiveMembership = member.getActiveMembership();
        model.UserPastMemberships = member.getExpiredMemberships();
        model.UserPayments = member.getUserPayments();
        model.UserStatistics = member.GetMembershipStatistics();
        if (model.UserActiveMembership != null)
        {
            model.DaysTillMembershipExpiry = member.getActiveMembership().daysTillExpiry();
        }

        return model;
    }
```

Then it is using cached data from the database and i do not know why?  Why would the same code called inline in the action be fine but when called from a seperate static function that it caches the data.

Any clues would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone got any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions have the line

```
Member member = db.Members.Single(m => m.AspNetUserId == user.Id);
```

but since this is now in 2 different classes it must also be 2 different `db`s.
The second one is static and will live longer (ie never refresh).

- Avoid `static`. The separation in 2 classes is a good idea but just make instances.
- Follow naming standards so that properties are easier to recognize.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do this now.